# How to deploy a second strapi project to server

Tags: node.js, deployment, strapi

Deploying the first one was relatively easy, I just moved the folder to the server and using 'strapi start' and 'npm start' from linux terminal gets it up and running.

Now I would like to add an additonal strapi project to a sub directory and run in, so it's accessible from the url mysite/second-project.

But how can I run another project simultanouesly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would strongly suggest using something like `pm2` to make your strapi node process to persist when you exit the shell...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably can't use the `<Host-Name>:80` to point towards two different strapi application since they run on different ports.

What you can do is specify your ngix or apache config to redirect specific folder structure to different strapi applications on different ports.

Suppose you have one application running on `port 8080` and another application on `port 8181` and then configure you nginx so that the incoming urls are redirected in such way:

```
                  +--- host --------> strapi application on localhost:8080
                  |
users --> nginx --|--- host/second-project ---> strapi application on localhost:8181
                  |
                  +--- host/mail ---> strapi application on localhost:8282
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Shababb
Just a question and I hopt it doesn't go off topic, but as far as I understand my backend has a port of <host-name>:443, that's how I can access the strapi interface. So does it mean that when creating a second application, I do need to assign it to a different port such as 8181 like you said, and also the backend to a new port? Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome. Yes you can't run two strapi application in one port. If you try to then you should get an error which says `Address already in use`

Comment: You might not have two applications running in the same port in the server but you can redirect incoming users towards two different applications in different ports even though the users are all hitting the same port.

Comment: Thanks Shababb but I didn't understand how on a single application I have the strapi port 1337 and the react port 3000 and then when having another project do I need to assign the users to another port instead of port 3000 or instead of port 1337, or both?
I know it's very basic I'm just confused, I can open a new question about this, thanks in advance

Comment: Depends on how you are designing your system. Are you using the react app as the front end app and connecting to the strapi application as your API? In that case you should be configuring your server to redirect users trying to connect to your server to the port where react is available.

Comment: You need to configure your server to map the public address and port to your local applications port.